# How can I properly handle greedy and optional patterns in python regex

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I have a variable which contains a path and I want to extract the 6th folder from the path, but the 7 folder may or may not occur.  In both cases... the regex should return "three", but the first example fails to match.  I tried using ? to indicate optional, but my attempt was incorrect.

What do I need to change in the regex to make it match in both cases:

```
path = "//network/path/folder/_one/two/three"  # fails 
path = "//network/path/folder/_one/two/three/four"  # works

p = re.compile('^//network/path/folder/_.*?/.*?/(.*?)/')   # compile the regex
m = re.search(p, path)    # regex search

if m:     # regex matched
    print "6th folder =",m.group(1)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `path.split('/')[7]` -> `'three'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could target lesser characters instead of `.*`

```
^//network/path/folder/_.*?/[^/]*/([^/]*)
```

http://regexr.com?356lh

`[^/]*` means any number of occurences of any character but NOT A FORWARD SLASH.
`^` is not flag.

Comment: that works, but what does [^/]* mean...  does it mean match all characters except /